# How to get the average of an array and round the result in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to get the average result rounded to 2 decimal places but my code is not working and I couldn't find any way to solve it.

```js
db.customers.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
      _id: "$customer.gender",
      "average age": {
        $avg: {
          $round: [
            "$customer.age",
            2
          ]
        }
      }
    }
}])
```

Comment: For clarity, could you edit your question and add an example input doc and the output shape you seek?

Comment: yea sure, I will see how I can optimize the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Age has no decimal digits, so i guess you want to round the average after the grouping like bellow, that uses the stage operator `$set` to add the new field. (`$set`=`$addFields`)

```js
db.customers.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$customer.gender",
      "average age": {
        $avg: "$customer.age"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "average age": {
        "$round": [
          "$average age",
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```